# bitnami/WordPress chart - embed uploads in a custom image

Tags: wordpress, docker

I am using bitnami/WordPress chart https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/wordpress/

I am looking for a way to use a custom image which embed a specific wp app state (plugins + themes + uploads) ... I know that for themes and plugins can be use a script to do that ... but I want to embed it all

I tried this:

- starting from https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-wordpress.git
- using docker-compose I installed locally wp using volumes
- all the generated wp content I copied it to rootfs folder then build and tag my custom image, then docker push to my repo
- updated values.yaml to use my custom image

After helm install and wait for WordPress pod to be ready ... the pod does not contain the uploads files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace image using custom values.yaml file.

For example you can create values.yaml containg this content

```
image:
  registry: "docker.tools.private.services"
  tag: 5.6.0-debian-10-r23
```

Documentation for all values, you can find in the [README.md for that chart](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/wordpress).

This docs are generated directly from values.yaml file, so you can use directly [the values.yaml file](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/master/bitnami/wordpress/values.yaml)

Then install it with helm:

```
helm install my-release bitnami/wordpress -f ./values.yaml
```

### Volume override

In the bitnami chart there is volume mount under the `/bitnami/wordpres`. Make sure it does not cover your image file system.

For example for me it is mount like this:

```
kubectl describe pod blog-wordpress-5698fc9584-jklhl
```

```
    Mounts:
      /bitnami/wordpress from wordpress-data (rw,path="wordpress")
...
...
...

Volumes:
  wordpress-data:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  slide-blog-wordpress
    ReadOnly:   false
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Already done this, I specified in my question "updated values.yaml to use my custom image".

I also tried to comment 
#. /post-init.sh
in https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-wordpress/blob/master/5/debian-10/rootfs/app-entrypoint.sh

Comment: Do you copy files into docker container with COPY command? Could you start your image in the kubernetes cluster, then do `kubectl exec -ti POD_IDENTIFIER bash` and see if files are missing or maybe user has no permissions for them? Because bitnami wordpress is working as non root user by default.

Comment: yes, I used COPY.
The weird thing is: with my custom image, locally, with docker compose the Wordpress container contain my "uploads" files but same image on k8s cluster ... does not contain
on kubectl exec -ti POD_IDENTIFIER bash ... nothing on my uploads
Seems to be fresh init install :)

Comment: Hmmm where do you copy uploads. There is option, kubernetes volume override your directory. Could you verify it with `kubectl describe pod POD_ID`. You can find section in volumes.

Comment: The uploads are in /bitnami/wordpress/wp-content/uploads, but are in the docker image.
First time, on helm install the volume is empty no? so is generated by deployment ...
Now I have
Mounts:
      /bitnami/wordpress from wordpress-data (rw,path="wordpress")

Comment: Yess, so mounted volume  `/bitnami/wordpress` shadows your uploads `/bitnami/wordpress/wp-content/uploads`. The option is to copy uploads for example to `/upload` when you build the image. Then add post hook to link this folder to `/bitnami/wordpress/wp-content/uploads`. You can do it like this: https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-wordpress/tree/master/5/debian-10/rootfs/post-init.d. You need to copy executable file to `/post-init.d `